# Django ORM Query Multiple Models Reverse Relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the main model and five sub-models out of five four models have foreignkey relationship and one model has a one-to-one relationship to the main model. I am trying to execute a query on the main model and fetch related records from the sub-model sorted by 'id' and select the first record. I tried multiple ways to achieve this but still, the total operation takes around 20secs to fetch around 6000 records. I would really appreciate any help to efficiently fetch data from these models.

```
Model M:
    id
    name
    status

Model SA:
    m = Foreignkey(M)
    sa1

Model SB:
    m = Foreignkey(M)
    sb1

Model SC:
    m = Foreignkey(M)
    sc1

Model SD:
    m = Foreignkey(M)
    sd1

Model SE:
    m = OneToOne(M)
    se1
```

I tired select_related, prefetch_related, but still not able to reduce the turn-around-time.

After trying different ways, currently, I am using the below, but from that, I get the only records which has data in the sub-models. But I would need to fetch all records from the main model irrespective of data in the sub-models.

```
data = M.objects.exclude(
    SA=None,
    SB=None,
    SC=None,
    SD=None,
    SE=None,
)
```

I am looking for output like:

```
{'id': 1212, 'name':'asdasd', 'sa1':'asdasda, 'sb1':'asdasda, 'sc1':'asdasda, 'sd1':'asdasda, 'se1':'asdasda}
```

Comment: Still on my baby steps on django, but have you used the explain feature to see the queries sent ? What is your db engine ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/optimization/#use-explain

Comment: When you say sorted by id and select the first, do you mean the lowest or highest id?

Comment: @Niloct db engine is Postgres, and I used the explain feature. But that was not that helpful.

Comment: @IainShelvington I sorted by highest id to get the last added record related to the Main model.

Comment: @Kaartz have you executed the sql queries outside django to test their performance ?